# how convert curl command to http method

Tags: flutter, http, curl

how convert this command curl  `$ curl -u app_id:app_secret -X GET {api}/auth_username`   to http method to use it in flutter

and the result:

```
  "meta": {
    "page": 1,
    "limit": 10,
    "count": 3
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "username": "api_user2"
    },
    {
      "username": "api_user1"
    },
    {
      "username": "test"
    }
  ],
  "code": 0
}
```

please help
thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code.

Comment: no code ready i have , just i want how convert this curl command to use it in flutter app by using get http method , and that is platfom i work https://docs.emqx.io/en/cloud/latest/api/auth.html#check-username-authentication-information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I submit data in nested JSON format using python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492446/how-do-i-submit-data-in-nested-json-format-using-python-requests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using http package ,
you request url become like this

```dart
String credentials = "$app_id:$app_secret";
var bytes = utf8.encode(credentials);
var encodedHead = base64.encode(bytes);

CLient().get(Uri.parse('https://$api/auth_username'),headers :
 "Authorization: Basic $encodedHead"
)
```

Comment: Thanks i will try that

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto your postman
2. Click on Import Button Text & Paste your curl &
   Click Continue
3. Then Click Code just
   below (Send / Save) Button

You will see the Generated Code Snippets

Comment: Thanks i will try that